# On rightclick of a tree item, a portion of the menu shows up behind the tree item in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using context menu from `react-contexify` and `TreeMenu` from `react-simple-tree-menu`.

When a user right clicks on an item in `treemenu`, the context menu is shown. However when a tree node is in focus, a portion of the context menu is showing up behind the tree node.

[image: menu1]

[image: menu2]

What could be the problem?

Code:

```
import TreeMenu from 'react-simple-tree-menu';
import { Menu, Item, Separator, Submenu, MenuProvider } from 'react-contexify';

const ContextMenuTree = () => (
  <Menu id='menu_idTree'  style={{  zIndex: '100' }}>
    <Item style={{  zIndex: '100' }} onClick={onCreateClick}>Create Folder</Item>
    <Item style={{  zIndex: '100' }} onClick={onDeleteFolderClick}>Delete Folder</Item>
  </Menu>
);

<div style={{  zIndex: '-1' }}>          
  <MenuProvider id="menu_idTree" style={{  display: 'inline-block', zIndex: '-1' }}>
  <TreeMenu style={{  zIndex: '-1' }} data={treeData} hasSearch="false"/>
  </MenuProvider>
  </div>
<ContextMenuTree style={{  zIndex: '1' }} > </ContextMenuTree>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely to be competing z-index values for the different elements. It seems like you're hard-coding the z-index value to -1 in both the `TreeMenu` and `MenuProvider` components. I'd suspect that when the tree node is in focus the same changed/different CSS classname that gives it a blue background colour also tinkers with its z-index.

Usually, anything that "pops up" (e.g. a context-menu) should have a z-index larger than its parent component, so that it's always on top.

Comment: Thanks for the response catchwa. But it did not help. As you can see from the updated code, the treemenu and menuprovider are not the 2 components with the trouble.    It is the ContextMenuTree (Z-index of 1) and MenuProvider(z-index of -1). Shouldn't contextMenuTree always show up n top? It does not! Do you know what is happening?

Comment: @tim You need to inspect the Poseidon-Data element from your screenshot when it's selected and see what it's z-index value is and what CSS class is causing it to be set that way.